# Wordpress Infinite Scroll Selectors

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, infinite-scroll

The infinite-scroll plugin (infinite-scroll.com) used to work on my site, but somehow it no longer does. I'm not sure what changed.

My site is www.outgrow.me

The content selector I'm using is .li_container:first and post selector .mcol

Any ideas what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome console outputs the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input http://outgrow.me/:1
```

Look at the end of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  mixpanel.track("Viewed Homepage",
    {"Title":"Homepage",
     "Date":"Friday",
</script>
```

There's a missing closing bracket and parenthesis:

```
});
```

And, since date is the last item in your JSON object, it shouldn't have a comma after it - this will cause problems in old versions of Internet Explorer.

**EDIT:** So that fixed the JS error, but infinite scroll is still not working. I suspect the problem is that your `.li_container` div is not in the page's source code.

The plugin you're using to create your columns (columnizer) inserts `.li_container` into the DOM, but does so AFTER the infinite scroll script runs, so infinite scroll has nothing to attach itself to. Place your columnizer scripts above the the infinite-scroll script, and I suspect that will fix the problem.

Comment: How do I find the missing close?